# preg_match_all() to count the 'pattern occurs' thing

Tags: php, regex

For example I have the following string    `1234567890`

pattern is `/1|2/`

```
preg_match_all('/1|2/', '1234567890', $out)
```

gives

```
 [0] ⇒ "1"
 [1] ⇒ "2"
```

But I need to know only the number when the whole pattern occurs (1 time in this case).
Is it possible to find it?

## In other words I need to count how many times all pattern occurs

P.S.
for 'closers' and 'downvoters': the question is much wider then just regexpings

Another example:
string `sdjka1gsdf1la5wlkasdfcmjsdc8fgvkj`
I need to count how many times occurs set of letters `a`, `b` and `c`, followed by digits.
As you can see in this example there'are three occurences - a1, a5 and c8.
So how I can count them?

Example 2:
String `where 1 abcd when 1 123456 where 5 when 10 abdc`
I need to count how many times `whe*+one digit` occurs (in this case 3 times)

Comment: Why is it one time? It is two times.

Comment: What do you mean by **whole pattern**? Your regex is `/1|2/` which means match either `1` or `2`

Comment: @u_mulder I need to count how many times all pattern occurs

Comment: @elDude still unclear. You might want to provide some clear input/expected output. Also maybe you're looking for `substr_count()` or `count_chars()` instead of a regex.

Comment: @HamZa `substr_count` doesn't support `regexp`, and my patterns are complicated enough. I'll try to write some examples to make it more clear, thanx, though

Comment: short example: I need to count `how many numbers followed by letters`

Comment: @elDude then add a simple `count()` to your code https://eval.in/527096 ?

Comment: that's convinient only while searching `letter+digit`. On other cases, I need to search for words or something more complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`preg_match_all` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

> **Return Values**
>   Returns the number of full pattern matches (which might be zero), or `FALSE` if an error occurred.

```
echo preg_match_all('/[abc]\d+/', 'sdjka1gsdf1la5wlkasdfcmjsdc8fgvkj');
```

`3`   [demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/527115)

Comment: How I can count words in this case? I mean, `multiple letters`?

Comment: @elDude This is just up to the pattern you use. For your second example try [`whe\w*\s+\d\b`](https://regex101.com/r/yR4mD9/2). [See demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/527129). This pattern matches literal `whe` followed by any amount of `\w` word characters, followed by `\s+` one or more whitespaces, followed by `\d` one digit and `\b` a boundary. [Here is the regex faq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean).

Comment: but when I looking for completely different words, then it seems impossible to put it in one pattern

Comment: I just found that `/(word1|word2|word3)/`is counted like one occurence.

Comment: @elDude The full pattern `1|2` matches two times in `1234567890`. Same like `[12]`. The full pattern `(word1|word2|word3)` matches 3 times in `word1 word2 word3 word4`. Same like `word[1-3]`.